# Parsing C X-Macro table

Tags: c, parsing, macros, metaprogramming

Now i have a table description using x-macros. Actually the table is quite large and should be updated from a database. I would like to know if there is some way to parse the table like this. For example, update a cell, update a row, update a column, insert a row, insert a column... I am very thankful if you give some advise how to do this. Which python package could do it...

```
  /* type    , name , elementid */
#define X_OBJ_MEMBER_TABLE\                         
  X( uint8_t , Var1 , ELEMENT_1 )\
  X( uint8_t , Var2 , ELEMENT_2 )\
  X( uint8_t , Var3 , ELEMENT_4 )\
```

Best Regards,

Comment: You can keep the X macro list in a header file of its own, then write some external script/prog that generates that file. And that's about it. If your question is how to generate a text file based on a database, that's a very broad question.

Comment: Why would you need to update partially, for example add column? Why not simply rewrite the entire X-macro file with your Python script when you need to add or remove something?

Comment: Yeah, @user694733 is on the right track. It'd be easier to write something that can parse a table like that into Python structures, and something that serializes those Python structures back to code.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the X macro construct you want to edit.